# How to fix problem with access data in postgresql with Flask and sqlalchemy (deploy on Render)?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, render

I have app that works well locally and on Heroku. Then I go from Heroku to Render and now it work but until it need to user register or login or any operations with db postgresql. I run python version 3.9.13 and postgres 14. Render run with the same versions and the same data and tables columns (and data in it) as locally.
The problem in Render:
When register or login (for example):

logs are:

```
Feb 4 08:29:57 PM  [2023-02-04 17:29:57,653] ERROR in app: Exception on /login [POST]
Feb 4 08:29:57 PM  Traceback (most recent call last):
Feb 4 08:29:57 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
Feb 4 08:29:57 PM      response = self.full_dispatch_request()
Feb 4 08:29:57 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1518, in full_dispatch_request
Feb 4 08:29:57 PM      rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
Feb 4 08:29:57 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1516, in full_dispatch_request
Feb 4 08:29:57 PM      rv = self.dispatch_request()
Feb 4 08:29:57 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1502, in dispatch_request
Feb 4 08:29:57 PM      return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
Feb 4 08:29:57 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/app/views/profile_views.py", line 20, in login
Feb 4 08:29:57 PM      company = Company.query.filter_by(company_name=company_name).first()
Feb 4 08:29:57 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2810, in first
Feb 4 08:29:57 PM      return self.limit(1)._iter().first()
Feb 4 08:29:57 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2894, in _iter
Feb 4 08:29:57 PM      result = self.session.execute(
Feb 4 08:29:57 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1691, in execute
Feb 4 08:29:57 PM      conn = self._connection_for_bind(bind)
Feb 4 08:29:57 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1532, in _connection_for_bind
Feb 4 08:29:57 PM      return self._transaction._connection_for_bind(
Feb 4 08:29:57 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 721, in _connection_for_bind
Feb 4 08:29:57 PM      self._assert_active()
Feb 4 08:29:57 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 601, in _assert_active
Feb 4 08:29:57 PM      raise sa_exc.PendingRollbackError(
Feb 4 08:29:57 PM  sqlalchemy.exc.PendingRollbackError: This Session's transaction has been rolled back due to a previous exception during flush. To begin a new transaction with this Session, first issue Session.rollback(). Original exception was: (psycopg2.errors.InFailedSqlTransaction) current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block
Feb 4 08:29:57 PM  
Feb 4 08:29:57 PM  [SQL: INSERT INTO companies (company_name, password_hash, yandex_disk_token, wb_api_token, wb_api_token2) VALUES (%(company_name)s, %(password_hash)s, %(yandex_disk_token)s, %(wb_api_token)s, %(wb_api_token2)s) RETURNING companies.id]
Feb 4 08:29:57 PM  [parameters: {'company_name': 'qwe', 'password_hash': 'pbkdf2:sha256:260000$6PWa3LW6YqHOYreb$f09919e59d32770e729ad8baf98a65ffd635db390539e4a89f9a19bbfd04e6ca', 'yandex_disk_token': 0, 'wb_api_token': 0, 'wb_api_token2': 0}]
Feb 4 08:29:57 PM  (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/2j85) (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/7s2a)
Feb 4 08:29:57 PM  False
Feb 4 08:29:57 PM  127.0.0.1 - - [04/Feb/2023:17:29:57 +0000] "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 500 290 "https://costavog.onrender.com/login?next=%2F" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
```

Maybe anybody stuck with similar problem?

the app on github:
https://github.com/KonstantinPR/costavog

site:
https://costavog.onrender.com/login

Comment: `PendingRollbackError` means that something has _already_ gone wrong in the transaction. You need to check the logs to find the error that occurred just before this one.

Answer (score 0):

The issues was in small mistake in logic:

company = Company.query.filter_by(id=current_user.id).first()

instead of

company = Company.query.filter_by(id=current_user.company_id).first()

but to check this it was valuable to connect from the local app to the Render postgres and it that way you can see all logs that far more deep than what you get from render, so just instead of link to the local postgres database use render postgres. It helped me to find out mistakes